# Change contents of a specific cell in multiple xlsx files in python

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm trying to write a python script that modifies/chnages contents of a cell of a particular sheet in all `.xlsx` sheets that exist in the current working directory.

The shape of the sheet in all the `.xlsx` is something like this:

`column1                    column 2`

`value1.1                   value2.1`

`value1.2                   value2.2`

`.`

`.`

`value1.n                   value2.n`

`.`

`.`

Apologies for improper formating, I don't know how to format so that the values look like cells, so imagine the above as 2 columns of a sheet.

Now, what I want is to open each `.xlsx` file, open the first sheet: "sheet", find `value1.n`, whcih is present in each sheet and modify `value2.n` to `value2.nm`, where `value2.nm` is the modified value.

Ultimately, i want the sheet to look like this:

`column1                    column 2`

`value1.1                   value2.1`

`value1.2                   value2.2`

`.`

`.`

`value1.n                   value2.nm`

`.`

`.`

whilst all other content remains untouched.

I already have code that can access the first sheet and find the `value1.n` i'm looking for, but I'm unable to proceed further.

Any help on this is appreciated.

```
import openpyxl
count = 0
for f in files:
    if f[-4:] == "xlsx":
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
        sheet = book.active
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(values_only=True):
            for data in row:
                if data == "value1.n":
                    count = count + 1
                    print(data)
                    print(count)
```

the print statements are just for me to keep track.

I'm using Windows 10, and coding on locally installed Jupyter Notebook that uses a Python3 notebook.

Comment: You can listdir and iterate on files us pandas make a dataframe make changes in row by pd.iterrows() then save it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import openpyxl
count = 0
for f in files:
    if f[-4:] == "xlsx":
        book = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
        sheet = book.active
        for idx, row in enumerate(sheet.iter_rows()):
            if row[0].value == "value1.n":
                row[1].value = count + 1
                count = count + 1
        book.save(f)
```

Comment: You want to update a `cell.value`, therefore remove `values_only=True` and you can do `row[1].value = count + 1`

Comment: Thanks @stovfl, I have modified the answer.